# Create a MySQL sproc from c#, delimiter issues

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create stored procedures from a c# program. It typically reads the sproc definition from a text file, and then run it against the chosen database.

My SQL script file looks like this:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MySproc;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE MySproc(           
                IN Id BIGINT,
                IN Reference VARCHAR(255),
                IN Bla VARCHAR(255)
    )
    BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TableA(`Id`, `Reference`) VALUES(Id, Reference);
                INSERT INTO TableB(`Id`, `Bla`) VALUES(Id, Bla);
    END
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

and this works fine in the workbench.
I then execute it with this type of c# code:

```
        using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = _mySqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlCommand.Connection = _mySqlConnection;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = scriptfile;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

And it errors with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
>   CREATE PROCEDURE MySproc(           IN Id BIGINT 
>     ' at line 1

If I remove the `DELIMITER //` stuff, then it still parses the semi colons between BEGIN and END as a delimiter for the outer statement, and it errors with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 31

Any idea how I can set either the Command or the something int he script so that it works? Not even sure if the error actually comes from MySQL itself, or from the MySqlCommand library (MySql.Data.6.9.9). And MySQL server is 5.6.25, InnoDB tables.

Comment: How are you reading the text file in?

Comment: DELIMITER is not mysql command. it is a function that uses by mysql client tools..

Comment: @levent, agreed delimiter is not a mysql command and is meant for mysql client tools. I initially had the 2nd error (near `'END' at line 31`) and made several attempts at fixing it, one of them using `DELIMITER`.  I should have turned the question the other way. Maybe the fix for me would be to find a "delimiter"-type of function implemented in MySql.Data library, since that's my "client".

Comment: @DanField, the text file is read elsewhere and passed in as a string to the method where the MySqlCommand part is. Would CR/LF things cause my problem? I'll experiment (although I doubt it).

Comment: U can show final commad text that delimiter removed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing the DELIMITER // with something like `delimiter $$`

Answer (score 0):

Pointless question, sorry, it's embarrassing. This morning, I created a unit test following the top part of this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html
and it works fine:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSprocCreationFromMySqlDoc()
    {
        // from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=;";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_emp";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emp";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE emp (empno INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20), birthdate DATE)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE add_emp(" +
                              "IN fname VARCHAR(20), IN lname VARCHAR(20), IN bday DATETIME, OUT empno INT)" +
                              "BEGIN INSERT INTO emp(first_name, last_name, birthdate) " +
                              "VALUES(fname, lname, DATE(bday)); SET empno = LAST_INSERT_ID(); END";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Then, I did another test with my own statements (trying to replicate file read from disk, with crlf) and it works too!

```
            cmd.CommandText =
                "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MySproc; " + Environment.NewLine +
                "CREATE PROCEDURE MySproc(" + Environment.NewLine +
                "IN Id BIGINT," + Environment.NewLine +
                "IN Reference VARCHAR(255)," + Environment.NewLine +
                "IN Bla VARCHAR(255))" + Environment.NewLine +
                "BEGIN " + Environment.NewLine +
                "INSERT INTO TableA(`Id`, `Reference`) VALUES(Id, Reference); " + Environment.NewLine +
                "INSERT INTO TableB(`Id`, `Bla`) VALUES(Id, Bla); " + Environment.NewLine +
                "END";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And then I ran my original application (that read scripts from files) and it runs ok as well! So I can't explain it. I'm wondering if I did something to the MySql server that affected all connections, or did something in one connection that stayed on, affecting all connections, until a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MySqlScript`. `MySqlScript` is automatically parsing
DELIMITER keyword among many other things.

This is a manual of how to use it:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript.html